# Detecting whether browser is fast enough for site

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

Feature detection is generally preferred over browser sniffing. What should I do in a case where certain browsers "support" the features I'm using but have javascript runtimes that are too slow?

I'm using the d3 library for some complicated visualizations. The visualization is very smooth in chrome / firefox, acceptable in IE9, and slow yet working in IE8. I'd like to display a banner to IE8 users telling them to upgrade and a notice banner to IE9 users that it would be faster in chrome or FF. Is it bad to do this via user agent sniffing?

Comment: you could ask them to use chromeframe, for starters: https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/

Comment: Good point; it'd be worth including that link in the banner. Doesn't solve my problem of when to show the banner (unless I just show it to everyone using any version of IE, which seems a little heavy-handed)

Comment: oh it wasn't intended to solve the problem, it would just reduce the potential number of people that would encounter it to begin with. and i show it to everyone using IE on my sites, they don't seem to mind. better than using IE8's Javascript renderer. :)

Comment: What is 'fast enough'? And why is IE8 not fast enough? If something is slow on your computer, it still could be fast on mine. You don't know what system I have.

Comment: I know that my customer base has on average slower machines than my MBA. Slow on my machine means unacceptably slow on my customers'. Buttery smooth on mine means probably ok on theirs. @arjan Is there a way I could check for the smoothness of d3 and display a banner if certain actions take > some amount of time?

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey, I'm curious. What do you mean by, and how do you measure, "they don't seem to mind"? I tend to think that such an intrusive warning must affect the user experience.

Comment: well i find in Google Analytics that I have a much higher percentage of visitors using Chromeframe than what I would expect, much closer to the percentage of IE users I would expect (~30%). And my IE users are below 5%. my conclusion is that they are installing chromeframe upon visiting my site. so I mean ... your thoughts are noted? not sure how to respond on what you think/guess user behavior is.

Comment: i should point out there is only one site that i ask for chromeframe on all versions of IE before 10. most of them i ask for it only on IE7-.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not measuring the time that the browser takes to compute something complex, similar to what you want to do, and set a threshold time for it?

```
function detectBrowserSpeed(){

    var i,
        slowThreshold = 100; // milliseconds
        startMillis = + new Date(); //The + is to 'force' casting to an integer representing EPOCH milliseconds. If + is ommited, then I get an instance of Date.

    //Do something complex here:
    for (i=0;i<100000;i+=0.1){

    }

    var elapsed = (+ new Date()) - startMillis;
    if(elapsed > slowThreshold){
        return 'slow';
    }else{
        return 'fast'; 
    }

}
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Time the visualization render and compare it to some acceptable threshold. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Can you add a comment for the `+` in startMillis = + new Date()?

Comment: I could have ommited the `+` in the `+ new Date()`, in both occurrences, but the idea is to be explicit that I am operating on milliseconds.

Comment: this is working pretty nicely. We're fading in a little "your browser is running slowly, think about upgrading" banner if render times go above 1000ms.